# Как слить эти 2 скрипта воедино?

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно для переключения темы на сайте + сохранение состояния чекбокса.
Как этот код можно слить в 1? Пытаюсь запустить по отдельности каждый в html и работает только второй, а первый отказывается.

```
    document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox1").forEach(el => {
        el.onchange = () => localStorage.setItem(el.id, el.checked);
        el.checked = localStorage.getItem(el.id) === "true";
    })


    function theme() {
        document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox").forEach(el => {
            el.onchange = () => {
                let el = document.documentElement
                if (el.hasAttribute('data-theme')) {
                    el.removeAttribute('data-theme')
                    localStorage.removeItem('theme')
                } else {
                    el.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
                    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark')
                }
            }
        })
    }
    theme()
```

Comment: `".checkbox1"` - `".checkbox"` - почему разные?

Comment: Опечатка. В коде оба .checkbox1. Уже решил проблему путем добавления к input type=checkbox доп. класс checkbox2 и изменив во втором скрипте checkbox1 на checkbox2

Comment: Это не решение. Вы все равно затираете вторым скриптом значение `onchange`. Решение - у меня в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //el.onchange = ...
    el.addEventListener('change', (evt) => ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Поместите, в самый конец перед body. Или второй способ использовать событие load или DOMContentLoaded в зависимости от потребностей.

```
<script>
 document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox1").forEach(el => {
            el.onchange = () => localStorage.setItem(el.id, el.checked);
            el.checked = localStorage.getItem(el.id) === "true";
        })
</script>
</body>
```