# Помогите исправить код plz

Tags: javascript, html, css

Задача этого чуда кода сохранять положение кнопки (что оно делает хорошо).
Менять тему (что оно тоже делает хорошо) и при этом сохранять последнюю выбранную тему (светлая и темная).

Проблема в том, что при перезапуске страницы кнопки остаются на своём положении как и должны, а вот тема отсутствует.
Исправляет всё это дело клацаньем несколько раз по чек боксу, но опять же тема сбрасывается на стандартную (белую).

Чек бокс с типом `type="checkbox"`. Смена темы происходит благодаря `:root[data-theme='dark']`

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox1").forEach(el => {
  el.onchange = () => {
    localStorage.setItem(el.id, el.checked)
    if (document.documentElement.hasAttribute('data-theme')) {
      document.documentElement.removeAttribute('data-theme')
      localStorage.removeItem('theme')
    } else {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark')
    }
  }
})

document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox1").forEach(el => {
  el.checked = localStorage.getItem(el.id) === "true";
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox1").forEach(el => {
    el.checked = localStorage.getItem(el.id) === "true";
})
if (localStorage.getItem('theme') == 'dark')) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
} else {
    document.documentElement.removeAttribute('data-theme');
}
```

Comment: Не изменяет тему сайта, но при этом, если есть key: theme value: dark, то тема ставится автоматически на темную. Не сохраняет theme dark в localstorage

Comment: Всё разобрался. Спасибо! Извините за неудобства...

Comment: @O.Zewmpc-ZZ1 Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @O.Zewmpc-ZZ1 Спасибо. Здесь тоже -   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1268114/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b8-2-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be/1268117#1268117